# Find exclusion date from EKEvent

Tags: eventkit, ekevent, ekeventstore, ekeventkit

If I create a recurring event in iOS and then delete some of the recurrence items, how do I find that out from the EKEvent object?  I'm not seeing where it stores the list of exclusions.

Comment: Hello, i'm trying to create a recurring event but escape some occurrences, did you find any approche to get them escaped dates ? any help is much appreciated.